# MPAndroidChart OnChartValueSelectedListener is being triggered even if click is outside of data

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using a bar-chart, and I am trying to call a function when the user clicks on an exact bar-chart entry, not anywhere around it. Would it be possible to restrict the touch area for a click on the exact data ?

Setting chart properties

```
    mChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
    mChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);
    mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    yAxis.setDrawLabels(false); // no axis labels
    yAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false); // no axis line
    yAxis.setDrawGridLines(false); // no grid line
    yAxis.setDrawZeroLine(true);
    yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
```

Setting data

```
    float barWidth;
    float barSpace;
    float groupSpace;

    barWidth = 0.8f;
    barSpace = 0f;
    groupSpace = 0f;

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals2 = new ArrayList<>();

    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(3f, deposit));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(3f, loan));

    BarDataSet set1, set2;
    set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "A");
    set2 = new BarDataSet(yVals2, "B");
    BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2);
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
```

Setting Value listeners

```
      mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new 
      OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
            e.getData();
            Log.d("VAL SELECTED",
                    "Value: " + e.getY() + ", xIndex: " + e.getX()
                            + ", DataSet index: " + h.getDataSetIndex());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {
            Log.d("BAR_CHART_SAMPLE", "nothing selected X is ");

        }
        });
```

Comment: please provide a sample of your code

Comment: @Boukharist will do, thx

Comment: @samwinston have you found soln to this issue?

Comment: @MalwinderSingh try https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/4350

Comment: @samwinston soln posted there is not clear. can u post soon as answer to this question?

Comment: @MalwinderSingh try it out, it was accepted by the user who posted the issue

Comment: I have posted soln here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3627#issuecomment-694661532